# Cannot determine argument specifications to use

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm having a problem with NSubstitute.
I have this short code:

```
ReportingCycleDeliveryRepository
.When(f => f.Add(Arg.Any<ReportingCycleDelivery>()))
.Do(x => RepCycleDeliveries.Add((ReportingCycleDelivery)x[0]));
```

So when my (void) method `ReportingCycleDeliveryRepository.Add()` is invoked with any ReportingCycleDelivery argument, it should add this item to my `RepCycleDeliveries` list.

But instead, it throws an exception:

*NSubstitute.Exceptions.AmbiguousArgumentsException*

"Cannot determine argument specifications to use.
Please use specifications for all arguments of the same type."

Why is that? Why can't NSubstitute determine the correct argument specifications to use? I am clearly providing a hint, that the argument can be any `ReportingCycleDelivery` item.

Comment: Might there be overloads of the Add method?

Comment: hmm my ReportingCycleDeliveryRepository.Add() method is a generic type: void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class; I think you are right. Is there a solution?

Comment: No, generics shouldn't be a problem. What I meant was if there was additional overloads of Add taking some more general parameter. But I guess not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change your code to the following and have it work the way you would like it to:

```
ReportingCycleDeliveryRepository
    .When(f => f.Add(Arg.Do<ReportingCycleDelivery>(
        x => RepCycleDeliveries.Add(x[0])));
```

It's hard to say exactly why you might get this error without seeing the code for `ReportingCycleDeliveryRepository` and `ReportingCycleDelivery`.